# How to invert image colors from black to white

Tags: inkscape, vector, svg, image-editing

Inkscape installed on Debian. How to invert [SVG](https://openclipart.org/download/336744/greek-meander-frame.svg) image colors from black to white?
Tried to select all the paths (Select all) and use extensions > color > negative - but this method don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Touch the 3 shapes.
2. Touch a color. I used orange just to play with it.

[image]

And Paul Johnson is right. There is no white background to be inverted. You need either to add one with color or use the SVG on, let's say a web page with a color background.

To avoid being lost when using white shapes on a white background, I do not use pure white while working with it.

Comment: Thank you for tips. I used the mouse pointer to touch the black ornament in some place. This made it possible then to change the color at the bottom panel.
Which 3 shapes did you have in mind? I'm still not sure how to change the background to transparent. I want to save without backrground - I need only white patterns. (for printing it on black material)

Comment: The background is already transparent. The 3 shapes are the inner circle, the outer, and the middle pattern. Depending on how you select them you select them separately or joined.

Comment: Just send it as it is to the printer, they probably need it... black, so they generate the prepress negative or positive to print it with white ink.

Answer (score 1):

Your shape has no strokes, all paths are closed areas filled with black. Doing exactly what you asked i.e. changing black fill color to white makes your shape invisible against white background. To make it visible again insert a colored background:

[image]

I'm afraid you have also secret hopes like make something black. If I'm right, reveal them, too to get an useful answer.

Comment: I want to save white pattern without background, I need only pattern (for printing it on black material)

Comment: @minto Not my business, but printing on solid black which already covers the surface needs something else than a printer which uses CMYK inks. You need opaque white ink. No idea which printer allows it.

Comment: The file is for t-shirt printing service, they using some special printer.

Answer (score 0):

Select everything, and in the Fill and Stroke panel, change the fill to White.

Note that this will make everything appear invisible, since a white object on a white background (the default in Inkscape) will not show up. Note also that this is not an actual white background, it is merely shown as white for display purposes. SVGs have no actual background.

You can then go to *Edit > File > Document Properties*, choose the chequered background option which shows transparent areas with a chequered pattern, then hit the Page colour square, and choose a light grey. Note that the colour you choose is not important as this is just a background for display purposes in Inkscape, and not a real background colour. This will make the white object visible again.

[image]

Comment: Well, but none of the above methods work for this simple SVG [image](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarze_Sonne#/media/Datei:BlackSun.svg). What is wrong?

Comment: @Minto That's only because it has strokes and fills, and so you'd need to change both to white, unlike the first example which only has fills. This is pretty basic stuff TBH. Perhaps have a look at this tutorial I found for you [on youtube](https://youtu.be/o86MLSQHtMg?si=JJZByl42HA6byNcP) - it describes the concepts and uses of strokes and fills.  This functionality exists in all vector image editors by the way, not just Inkscape.